# UML tool for reverse engineering a Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, reverse-engineering

I am currently working on a Java project with `"IBM Rational Software Architect"(Licensed Version)` as an IDE .My task is to understand the code flow and need to prepare Technical Document as the project is  very big (a lot of codes, classes, packages, etc) and undocumented. Since, the project is written in Java, my idea was to reverse engineer this  project to see its architecture in UML. Do suggest me any open source  software/ plugin that suits my IDE and  can complete the task very easily?

I googled and found many useful Tools for Eclipse IDE but not for IBM Rational Software Architect.

Thanks for your answer !!

Comment: I was under the impression that you could create UML or at least visual diagrams from Rational Software Architect. Here is a link to show what I am referring to ... http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/tutorials/r-radvisualtools/rradvisualtools.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StarUML](http://staruml.io/) is a good open source tool, I think it have what you desire.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider stand-alone products. For generating sequence diagrams and jar dependencies dynamically try [jSonde](https://bedrin.github.io/jsonde/)

Static code analysis will suit for class diagrams - any modern IDE (like [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)) can generate it

Answer (score 0):

You can try "Modelio" which is Open Source and can reverse and generate class diagram.